# How to separate a substring in a complicate string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

For example:

```
str = "A=sample_text1; B=sample_text2; C=sample_text3;";
```

How can I get the text after "A=", which is "sample_text1" out ? (the length of sample_text1 can be very long, so str.substring won't work here)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your string has a structure where there are multiple fields where each field is represented as:

```
[KEY]=[VALUE];
```

You can use common string and array methods like `split` and `map` to extract what you need. In this case looks like you want the value of the first field:

```js
const str = 'A=sample_text1; B=sample_text2; C=sample_text3;';

const result = str.split(';').map(s => s.split('=').pop().trim()).shift();

console.log(result); //=> 'sample_text1'
```

Answer (score 0):

https://regexr.com is very useful for creating and testing regex.

```js
const match = "A=sample_text1; B=sample_text2; C=sample_text3;".match(/A=([^;]*)/);
let value = match !== null ? match[1] : undefined;
```

Would allow you to get the value of `A` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to capture every group surrounded by a `=` and a `;`:

```js
const str = "A=sample_text1; B=sample_text2; C=sample_text3;";
const regexp = "=(.*?);";
const values = [...str.matchAll(regexp)];
const aValue = values[0][1];
console.log(aValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be an overkill, but to easily access to all the keys / values, you could use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
let str = "A=sample_text1; B=sample_text2; C=sample_text3;";

let values = Object.fromEntries(
  str
  // Split all the pairs
  .split(";") 
   // Remove the last empty element
  .slice(0,-1)
  // map to a [key, value] array to pass to Object.fromEntries
  .map(i => i.split("=").map(j => j.trim()))); 

// get a value using a key
console.log(values["A"]) // sample_text1

// check if a key is present
console.log("C" in values) // true
console.log("D" in values) // false
```

It looks more longer than it is due the comments and the console logs, it can fit in one line.

Notice that this is assume of course that neither the character `=` or `;` can be part of the key or the value.